# How to give a function an argument in batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

How can I give a function an argument in batch? For example take a simple little hello world script:

```
:hello
    @echo Hello World!

goto :hello
```

How can I take this "function" an argument and output "world!" if nothing is given? For example:

```
:hello <name>
    if %name%=="" (
        @echo Hello World!
    ) else (
        @echo Hello %name%!
    )
```

Is there a correct way to give a function arguments in a batch script? I've done some research and the only thing I can really find is passing files and `ARGV` to the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments are referenced as `%1` for the first, `%2` for the second etc. See `call /?`:

```
call :hello Jake
@echo ===============
call :hello
goto :eof

:hello 
  if "%~1"=="" (
    @echo Hello World!
  ) else (
    @echo Hello %1!
  )
```

The first `call` provides one argument to the routine `:hello`, the second`call` provides no arguments